# Deriving Lorentz transformations

Tags: special-relativity, inertial-frames, coordinate-systems, lorentz-symmetry

I know this is gonna sound *backward* reasoning. But still, just for the sake of curiosity:

Is it possible to use just Lorentz Contraction and Time Dilation along with the lorentz factor $\gamma$ to derive the Lorentz transformations from one inertial frame to another? If not, what other assumptions are necessary?

Comment: What would you want to assume about the contraction / dilation? Would you want to simply allow their possibility and see what's compatible with other basic assumptions or begin with the Lorentz factor $\gamma = \sqrt{1-v^2}^{-1}$ as a given?

Comment: @WetSavannaAnimal aka Rod Vance  Yep, assuming the value of $\gamma$.

Comment: You probably need to assume that directions perpendicular to the velocity are not contracted.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We assume that Lorentz transformations are linear and that the origin in one frame maps to the origin in another frame (we do this in the usual derivation of Lorentz transformations as well!). Then, the general form is
$$
t' = a t + b x\,,\qquad x' = c t + d x \,.
$$
Since the transformations are linear, this also implies
$$
\Delta t' = a \Delta t + b \Delta x\,,\qquad \Delta x' = c \Delta t + d \Delta x \,.
$$

**Time Dilation**

This states that if $\Delta x = 0$, then $\Delta t' = \gamma \Delta t$. Thus, $a=\gamma$. Inversely, if $\Delta x' = 0$ then $\Delta t = \gamma \Delta t'$. This implies $d = \gamma ( ad - b c )$.

**Length Contraction**

This states that if $\Delta t' = 0$, then $\Delta x' = \frac{ \Delta x}{ \gamma }$. This implies $a=\gamma(ad-bc)$. Inversely, if $\Delta t = 0$, then $\Delta x = \frac{ \Delta x'}{\gamma}$. This implies $d=\gamma$. Using these equations, we can obtain
$$
a = d = \gamma \,,\qquad b c  = \gamma^2 - 1 = \frac{\gamma^2 v^2}{C^2}
$$
EDIT - I'm using $C$ for the speed of light so as not to confuse with the coefficient $c$.

With this, we can write a generic Lorentz transformation as
$$
t' = \gamma   t - \frac{\gamma v}{C^2 } f(v)  x \,,\qquad x' = \gamma x - \frac{\gamma v}{f(v)} t\, .
$$
for some function $f(v)$. We can now study some properties of this function.

First, we note the inverse Lorentz transform takes the form
$$
t = \gamma t' + \frac{\gamma v}{C^2} f(v) x' \,,\qquad x= \gamma x' + \frac{ \gamma v }{ f(v) } t' 
$$
The two must be related via $v \to - v$. Thus, we must have $f(v) = f (-v)$.

I don't think we can say more about $f(v)$ without additional input! Let me add one additional input and complete the derivation.

**Constancy of Light Speed**

This requires that if $x=Ct$ then $x'=Ct'$. This immediately implies $f(v)=1$.

Comment: What do you mean "Solving these equations" before the last step?

Comment: @PhyEnthusiast - That was misleading wording. I have edited it.

Comment: But how do you use the product bc to find what b and c are seperately?

Comment: I cannot fix $b$ and $c$ separately. That's what the function $f(v)$ was introduced for.

Comment: yeah but how do you know $b = -\frac{\gamma v}{c^2} f(v)$

Comment: In other words, how do you know that $bc^2/ (\gamma v)$ depends only on $v$

Comment: what else could it depend on? The only variable in the game is $v$.

Comment: Yeah, I don't know what I was thinking. Of course.

Comment: Excellent answer, btw. Thnx.

Comment: You read my mind. I was going to ask whether you would like to avoid confusing the coefficient $c$ and the speed of light

Answer (score 1):

Actually, you can do it with length contraction *alone* - provided you apply it symmetrically: first for the forward transform
$$x - vt = \sqrt{1 - (v/c)^2} x',\label{A}\tag{A}$$
and second for the backward transform
$$x' + vt' = \sqrt{1 - (v/c)^2} x.\label{B}\tag{B}$$
All you need to do now is substitute for $x'$ from ($\ref{A}$) into ($\ref{B}$) and solve for $t'$ to get the forward transform for $t'$; or substitute for $x$ from ($\ref{B}$) into ($\ref{A}$) and solve for $t$ to get the backward transform for $t$.

Actually, you don't even need the specific value of the length contraction either. You could just as well write
$$x - vt = Ax', \hspace 1em x' + vt' = Ax,$$
and then assert that $c$ be an Absolute Speed; i.e. that if you substitute $x = ct$ into this relation then you should get $x' = ct'$. That condition pins down what $A$ should be, as a function of $v$, up to a choice of $+$ or $-$ sign.

What I'm going to do instead is ...

I'll show you the (now standard) way that Lie developed to address problems like this. It is the way to comprehensively handle the issue of *all* symmetry transforms.

The starting point is that we want this:
$$βt^2 - αx^2$$
to remain invariant. For Relativity, we have $αβ > 0$, which (according to the invariant) would make $ᴄ ≡ \sqrt{β/α}$ an Absolute Speed that is both finite and non-zero. That's the actual starting point of (the ironically-named) Relativity. So, we could set $(α,β) = (1/ᴄ^2,1)$ and proceed from there, just to make it more definite. But it is more illustrative to keep $(α,β)$ intact. In the process we can also derive the Galilei transforms - which is the case where $ᴄ = ∞$, i.e. where $α = 0$ and $β ≠ 0$ (which, again we could make more definite by setting $β = 1$).

The first thing we notice is that under a small, infinitesimal change, we have:
$$2βt·Δt = 2αx·Δx.$$
This allows us to write
$$Δx = -βυt, \hspace 1em Δt = -αυx \label{1}\tag{1}$$
for some parameter $υ$. So, our transform is a one-parameter family of transforms. Out of that will, somehow, come a velocity.

Since the transform mixes $x$ and $t$ (linearly!) then the finite form of the transform will look like:
$$x' = A(u) x + B(u) t, \hspace 1em t' = C(u) x + D(u) t,\label{2}\tag{2}$$
where $u$ is the finite form of the parameter $υ$, i.e. $Δu = υ$. So, we gradually ramp up $u$, starting from $u = 0$, at which point $(x',t')$ and $(x,t)$ should coincide:
$$A(0) x + B(0) t = x, \hspace 1em C(0) x + D(0) t = t.\tag{3a}$$
Thus:
$$A(0) = 1, \hspace 1em B(0) = 0, \hspace 1em C(0) = 0, \hspace 1em D(0) = 1.\tag{3b}$$

To find out how these coefficients trend with $u$, we apply ($\ref{1}$) - not to $(x,t)$, but to $(x',t')$ in ($\ref{2}$) - by first evaluating $Δx$ and $Δt$:
$$Δx' = A'(u)Δu x + B'(u)Δu t, \hspace 1em Δt' = C'(u)Δu x + D'(u)Δu t,$$
setting $Δu = υ$, and then substituting in to get:
$$
A'(u)υ x + B'(u)υ t = Δx' = -βυt' = -βυ(C(u) x + D(u) t), \\
C'(u)υ x + D'(u)υ t = Δt' = -αυx' = -αυ(A(u) x + B(u) t).
$$
Separating out the $x$ and $t$ parts from each of the two conditions, we get:
$$A'(u) = -βC(u), \hspace 1em B'(u) = -βD(u), \hspace 1em C'(u) = -αA(u), \hspace 1em D'(u) = -αB(u).$$

That leads to the following initial value problem:
$$
A(0) = 1, \hspace 1em \frac{dA}{du} = -βC, \hspace 1em C(0) = 0, \hspace 1em \frac{dC}{du} = -αA, \\
B(0) = 0, \hspace 1em \frac{dB}{du} = -βD, \hspace 1em D(0) = 1, \hspace 1em \frac{dD}{du} = -αB.\label{3}\tag{3}
$$

Transforms like this have the property that if you iterate them, you eventually wrap back around to something involving lower iterations of the transform. Here, this is seen as follows:
$$
Δ^2x = Δ(Δx) = Δ(-βυt) = -βυΔt = αβυ^2x, \\
Δ^2t = Δ(Δt) = Δ(-αυx) = -αυΔx = αβυ^2t.
$$
They satisfy the *characteristic equation* $Δ^2 = αβυ^2$. For our case at hand, that shows up by taking second derivatives, where you find the same thing, except for the $υ$'s having been factored out. We actually have a second order initial value problem, where we now include the initial values $A'(0)$, $B'(0)$, $C'(0)$ and $D'(0)$ (obtained by setting $u = 0$ in ($\ref{3}$)):
$$
A(0) = 1, \hspace 1em A'(0) = 0, \hspace 1em \frac{d^2A}{du^2} = αβA(u), \\
B(0) = 0, \hspace 1em B'(0) = -β, \hspace 1em \frac{d^2B}{du^2} = αβB(u), \\
C(0) = 0, \hspace 1em C'(0) = -α, \hspace 1em \frac{d^2C}{du^2} = αβC(u), \\
D(0) = 1, \hspace 1em D'(0) = 0, \hspace 1em \frac{d^2D}{du^2} = αβD(u).
$$

That puts the spotlight on the following initial value problem:
$$g(0) = a, \hspace 1em g'(0) = b, \hspace 1em g''(u) = λ g(u).$$
Let the general solution be written as:
$$g(u) = γ_λ(u) a + σ_λ(u) b.$$
Different cases arise depending on the sign of $λ$, which for us is: $λ = αβ$. For our problem - the Lorentz transform - $αβ > 0$. For the Galilei transform - or the transforms for *any* geometry where either $α = 0$, $β = 0$ or both - $λ = 0$. For a transform in 4-D Euclidean space, where $t$ is just another spatial coordinate, we would have $αβ < 0$. The values of $γ_λ(u)$ and $σ_λ$ in each of these cases are:
$$\begin{align}
γ_λ(u) = \cosh{\sqrt{λ}u}, \hspace 1em & σ_λ(u) = \frac{\sinh{\sqrt{λ}u}}{\sqrt{λ}} & (λ > 0), \\
γ_λ(u) = 1, \hspace 1em & σ_λ(u) = u & (λ = 0), \\
γ_λ(u) = \cos{\sqrt{-λ}u}, \hspace 1em & σ_λ(u) = \frac{\sin{\sqrt{-λ}u}}{\sqrt{-λ}} & (λ < 0).
\end{align}$$

Thus, omitting the $λ = αβ$ for brevity, we get:
$$A = γ, \hspace 1em B = -βσ, \hspace 1em C = -ασ, \hspace 1em D = γ.$$
So, setting $w = σ/γ$, the transform becomes:
$$x' = γ(x - βwt), \hspace 1em t' = γ(t - αwx).$$

The functions satisfy the identity:
$$\left(γ_λ\right)^2 - λ\left(σ_λ\right)^2 = 1.$$
For our problem, that means:
$$1 = γ^2 - αβσ^2 = γ^2\left(1 - αβw^2\right) \hspace 1em⇒\hspace 1em γ = ±\frac{1}{\sqrt{1 - αβw^2}}.$$

For the cases $αβ ≥ 0$, the function $γ(u) > 0$, and there is no cross-over point, so we're forced to choose the "+" root. For the Euclidean case, $αβ < 0$, it doesn't matter which sign we choose, since we're talking about ordinary rotations and a 180-degree rotation reverses signs.

Finally, we can pin this down to something involving a velocity. In terms of dimension - within the broader setting of our problem - we have units $[x] = L$ for length, $[t] = T$ for time and $[u] = [υ] = [w] = S$ for speed and $S$ is being treated independently from $(L,T)$. This gives the coefficients the dimensions $[α] = T/(SL)$, $[β] = L/(ST)$.

So, $n = αw$ can be thought of as a speed measured in "marathon runner" units (e.g. minutes per mile), since $[αw] = T/L$. We could call that "slowness", because if you've ever run a marathon ... you know first-hand. If we make that substitution, our transform looks like this:
$$x' = γ\left(x - \frac{n}{ᴐ^2}t\right), \hspace 1em t' = γ\left(t - nx\right) \hspace 1em γ = \frac{1}{\sqrt{1 - (n/ᴐ)^2}}.$$
In it, the absolute speed is written as an absolute slowness: $ᴐ = \sqrt{α/β}$.

And, last of all, $v = βw$ can be thought of as speed measured in sprinter units (MPH or miles per hour), since $[βw] = L/T$, because if you're a sprinter and you're measuring speed in miles per minute then either you're going too far or you're going too slow. Here, the transform looks like this:
$$x' = γ\left(x - vt\right), \hspace 1em t' = γ\left(t - \frac{v}{ᴄ^2}x\right) \hspace 1em γ = \frac{1}{\sqrt{1 - (v/ᴄ)^2}}.$$

In the case of the Galilei transform, the Absolute Speed $ᴄ = ∞$ is infinite. That's the speed at which "simultaneous" happens. So, another way of saying the same thing is that "simultaneity" is absolute. That's the case of zero Absolute Slowness: $ᴐ = 0$, since $ᴐ = 1/ᴄ$. Since $γ = 1$, the transform can then be written as:
$$x' = x - vt, \hspace 1em t' = t.$$

The other place where $γ = 1$ is with the geometry that has infinite Absolute Slowness $ᴐ = ∞$, a.k.a. zero Absolute Speed $ᴄ = 0$. That's the geometry where things are so slow that even when they're running they're still standing still. Since that's the Alice In Wonderland world, it's called the Carrollian geometry. In it, the transform has a "simultaneity shift", but no motion:
$$x' = x, \hspace 1em t' = t - nx.$$

I left out the case $(α,β) = (0,0)$. That's the "static geometry" where *all* speeds are absolute and the only transform is
$$x' = x, \hspace 1em t' = t.$$

So, Carroll and Lorentz have simultaneity shift, and Galilei and Static don't, but have "absolute time". Galilei and Lorentz have motion in the spatial coordinates, while Carroll and Static don't, but have "absolute space". In all the cases, except Static, there is only room for one Absolute Speed, be it zero, finite or infinite.

And the Euclidean case has none of the above, because there's no speed or time in it, just angles and slopes. It's not a 3+1-dimensional space-time, but a 4-dimensional timeless-space.

Answer (score 0):

If we assume t' and x' as linear functions of t and x, we can write:
t′=at+bx,   (1)
x′=ct+dx.   (2)   or Δt′=aΔt+bΔx, (3) and   Δx′=cΔt+dΔx. (4) from (2) if x'=0,
x= -ct/d , so -c/d=v, and if x=0, x'=ct, and from (1) t'=at, so
x'=ct'/a,and c/a=-v,so from the definition of relative velocity we get d=a,and
c=-av,
x'=ax -avt    (6)    t'=at+bx (5)   and now if two snapshots   from  1-meter-rods
in two  inertial system are equal, so from (6) at t=0    if x'=1    x=1/a
and from (5) at (t'=0 if x=1), at=-b and from (6) x'=a+bv  and acc. to the relativity x=x', this results b=(1/a-a)/v, and we get the general transformation equations without gamma.
x'=a(x-vt)         (7)
t'=at-[(a-1/a)/v]x (8)
If a=1 you get Galileo Transformation, and if x=ct , x'=ct' then you get the LT.
but time dilation and length contraction can be find in general form too, and these  are not specific property of STR.